# Sequelize Error: Named bind parameter "$amount" has no value in the given object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

This is my sequelize code:

```
const insertQuery = `
    INSERT INTO transaction (amount, company_id, user_id, journal_id, type, account_id, plaid_transaction_id)
    SELECT $amount, $company, $user_id, $journal_id, $type, $account_id, $plaid_transaction_id
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM transaction WHERE plaid_transaction_id = $plaid_transaction_id
    )
    RETURNING id, amount, company_id, user_id, journal_id, type, account_id, plaid_transaction_id;
  `;


const bindParams: any = transactionData.map(({ amount, company_id, user_id, journal_id, type, account_id, plaid_transaction_id }) => ({
  amount,
  company: company_id,
  user_id,
  journal_id,
  type,
  account_id,
  plaid_transaction_id,
}));

 // Generate the SQL query with interpolated bind parameters
 const resolvedQuery = insertQuery.replace(/\$\w+/g, match => {
  const paramName = match.substring(1); // Remove the $ sign
  const paramValue = bindParams[0][paramName]; // Assuming the first element contains all params
  return sequelize.escape(paramValue); // Ensure proper escaping
});

console.log("Resolved SQL Query:", resolvedQuery);

 

  const insertedRows = await sequelize.query(insertQuery, {
    bind: bindParams,
    type: QueryTypes.INSERT,
    transaction: transactionObj,
  });

  return insertedRows;
```

I'm getting error: Named bind parameter "$amount" has no value in the given object.

This is my resolved sql query (which verifies that the data I'm passing is correct):

```
INSERT INTO transaction (amount, company_id, user_id, journal_id, type, account_id, plaid_transaction_id)
    SELECT 89.4, 42, 48, 293, 'debit', 1858, 'rkA3lL4bxxf4Jvv9x4gaibxXQjlaLlC7kb4mL'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM transaction WHERE plaid_transaction_id = 'rkA3lL4bxxf4Jvv9x4gaibxXQjlaLlC7kb4mL'
    )
    RETURNING id, amount, company_id, user_id, journal_id, type, account_id, plaid_transaction_id;
```

Comment: You go to all the trouble of building `resolvedQuery`, but then you pass `insertQuery` into the Sequelize operation ... (maybe that's just debugging?)

Comment: Oh wait wait, you pass `bindParams` into the Sequelize operation, but your `bindParams` value is an *array*. Are you sure you don't want `bindParams[0]`? (It's not clear why you're building it with `.map()` from the code posted.)

Comment: @Pointy I'm inserting multiple items. The reason I logged bindParams[0] was just to see the resolved query

Comment: I'm not using bulkInsert because I need to avoid inserting duplicates. Hence, this raw query. And I had to detect duplicates based on `plaid_transaction_id` and that column is nullable so can't use unique index on that. If there's a better alternate way, I'd love to hear that since SQL isn't my strong point.

Comment: Well it sounds like you're expecting Sequelize to do something pretty weird. A simple `INSERT ... SELECT` *can* insert multiple rows into the target table, but that's when there's a `FROM` clause that selects rows from another existing table. In your case, there is no table; there's just an array of binding values, but SQL doesn't have a way to directly express that.

Comment: (well no way to express that with a predicate, as you're trying to do)

Comment: True. I have changed the approach now and it's working.

Comment: `bulkCreate` has `ignoreDuplicates` option

Comment: Yes, but it requires you to set up a unique index as it ignores duplicates based on that.